# Aperte WorkFlow in lifery 6.0

Tags: workflow, liferay-6

How can i integrate an aperte workflow in lifery 6.0.6?
I have installed moven and the lifery 
but i can not added the aperteworkflow in the platform lifery 
please give me all the step.s